# How to format json data in php

Tags: php

I have created a webservice and return data in json but on API testing site showing response not in formatted form.

My code is as below :

```
return json_encode(array("Data" => array("data" => "hello","data2" => "hello1")),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[image]

How to get it?

Comment: What's wrong with the regular output? But I guess you could set the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag. https://secure.php.net/json_encode

Comment: Already tried `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`, but not working.

Comment: It does. https://3v4l.org/tnCjA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to

```
return json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This will give you pretty print of JSON format. Also what you have done should be working fine but what could be wrong is you are missing the JSON header.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks, `header('Content-Type: application/json');` work for me without `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag.

Comment: Great, try to use the json_preety_print as well to clean you json data and make it readable

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
echo json_encode(
  array(
    'error' => array(
      'error_message' => 'Please choose a date and time',
      'error_code' => 500,
    )
  )
);
?>
```